# Cannot get data from service after migrating to AngularJS 1.6.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

After migrating to AngularJS 1.6.3, I changed my services like below:

Here is my service:

```
MetronicApp.factory('MyService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
    get: function(id, success, error) {
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/quotation/' + quotationid).then(success,error);
    }
  }
}]);
```

and in ui-router, I'm resolving the data like this.

```
data: function(MyService, $stateParams) {
    return MyService.get($stateParams.id);
}
```

But in the controller, data comes undefined. Where am I wrong?

Comment: i would avoid unpromisefying code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you're not returning anything from `success`/`error` callback functions. Rather I'd suggest to remove `.then(success,error);` from `get` method. and then just call service get method 
from resolve.

```
data: function(MyService, $stateParams) {
    return MyService.get($stateParams.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using the following code in the service part just:

```
get: function(){
    return $http.get(url);
}
```

without any callbacks applied, and in the calling code:

```
service.someMethod().then(function (result) {
      var data = result.data;
}
```